# How i get the value (content) of a form in html

Tags: python, html, django, request

I wanna get the value of `{{q.op1}}` in html. How can I fix this?

```
 <div class="form-check">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answer" id="gridRadios1" value="option1" checked>
     <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
            {{q.op1}} # here
     </label>
</div>
```

If I use in views.py `request.POST.get(q.op1)` I get None but I want the value of the choice.

Comment: Do you consider to use a <form> tag? If you don't, then you need to write ajax request in javascript.

Comment: show your view. did you pass the q object in context?

Comment: if request.method == 'POST':
       
        questions = QuesModel.objects.filter(kategorie__exact="math I")
        print(questions)
        for q in questions:
           ...
            answer = request.POST.get(q.op1) 
           ....
return render(request, 'result.html', context)

Comment: with `request.POST.get(q.op1)` you are trying to get the value of input from your HTML that has the name `g.op1` and it doesn't exist. the only input we see in your question is an input with the name `answer`. strongly recommend adding your views.py and more HTML codes to get better help